# Client.Create method returns tcm:0-0-0 for Component.Id

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

I have following code for creating new Component in Tridion:

```
 ComponentData componentData = (ComponentData)client.Create(component, new ReadOptions());
```

However, once I try to read `Component.Id` property, it is returning new TCM URI (`tcm:0-0-0`). No need to say that I tried to set flags for `ReadOptions` or even `SynchronizationOptions`, but nothing seems to work. 
Also, I don't want to read Component again after save, I just want ID to return.

Comment: For clarity: are you testing `component.Id` or `componentData.Id`?  The first is the delta object you pass in (delta compared to default values) and may indeed have a `tcm:0-0-0` identifier. The latter is the created Component’s data and that is expected to have a regular TCM URI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is expected behavior, you will get an ID after a Save. You don't really need to "read Component again", as the Save (or Update) method returns a `IdentifiableObjectData`, so you can do something along the lines of:

```
componentData = (ComponentData)client.Save(whateverGoesInHereCan'tRemember);
```

Comment: Exactly, It persists the component data in the database only when you call save() and generates a new tcm id

Comment: Actually, I used following method with default read options, and it still returns new tcmuri:   ComponentData componentData = (ComponentData)client.Save(component, ReadOptions);

Comment: I just wanted to make an update. I had some code issues previously, but to make everything clear after additional testing: both create, update and save return tcmid.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was just about to go test it myself, as I was really sure this would work :)